# Cant erase or format samsung microsd

Tags: format, micro-sd

I have a samsung 16gb microsd i cant write or format on it. Now it doesnt mount on ubuntu but gparted detects it. I tried ubuntu format, gparted, low level hdparm, with no sucess. Hope someone can help

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a micro sd in a computer, it is likely in an adapter. Check if the adapter has a write lock switch.